# RVIZ weird tf values

Tags: arduino, rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use rviz on ROS fuerte and arduino by rosserial.

Arduino receives angles value from IMU and x,y position from encoders.
Hence i use transform tf to publish pose of /odom frame wrt /base_frame.

In rviz i set TF to see the 2 reference frames but i obtain different values than the ones arduino publishes. In fact if i fix position x=y=z=1 and fill quaternion values with my IMU angles, rviz shows me different position x,y,z values varying in time and quaternion values x,y,z that are negative wrt real one.

But if I run "rostopic echo tf" i can see that arduino broadcasts the exact values.

Moreover if i fix position x=y=z=0 i obtain in rviz the exact values. But if i fix position x=y=z=2 i obtain in rviz x,y,z position values that are twice the one obtained fixing x=y=z=1.

Someone can help me??

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61618/rviz-weird-tf-values/) by [GioRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4280/gioros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, RViz only shows the position/orientation relative the Fixed Frame, so that doesn't necessarily directly correspond to what's in the tf messages.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0